# Android Studio no syntax highlighting

Tags: react-native, android-studio, intellij-idea

Okay, I've wanted to give React Native a try, did a fresh install of Android Studio 4.1.1 on my Ubuntu 19.10, bootstrapped a simple project via `react-native` CLI, opened it and instantly noticed that JSX highlighting is broken, google around, but the only thing I found is this link -
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000161950-JSX-Syntax-Highlighting-not-working

Tried to reboot, to create a new project from scratch, I did not load my PyCharm settings when installed Android Studio, have not installed any plugins yet. So yeah - any ideas how do I get my highlighting working?

[image]

**UPD:** code navigation also seems to be broken. May be I need to try other version of Android Studio...

[image]

**UPD 2:** Tried Expo with Typescript project setup, studio asked to install a plugins that supports tsx, then restarted and now even the comments are not supported lol.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Android Studio does not have support for JavaScript. You may want to try [IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/react-native.html) or [WebStorm](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/developing-mobile-apps-with-react-native-in-webstorm/) if you do not need to work with Java.

Comment: Lol, never would have thought that JS is not supported there. Thank you!